# How to figure out a value of a variable?

Tags: java

In each of the following parts, what is the value of v after the code has been executed?

```
int v;
v = 0;
for ( int i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++ ) {
    for ( int j=1 ; j<=4 ; j++ ) {
        v = v + 1; 
    };
};
```

Can someone run me through the thought process on how to determine what the value for `v` would be?

Comment: 20? looks like we are just adding 1 to v 20 times

Comment: you could use a print statement to make it show you the value of v

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger.  This is something you can actually *observe* rather than ask people.

Comment: Step through it on a debugger.  Or just walk through the code and write it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner loop, since `j` starts with `1` and ends with `4`. Running through the number of times j is incremented, we know that the `v = v+1;` clause is executed four times.

In the outer loop, the same principle applies but with `5`, and this tells us that *the inner loop runs five times*.

So the inner loop runs five times, and the inner loop runs the `v = v+1` clause four times. Now we know that the `v = v + 1;` clause runs 20 times (`5*4 = 20`).

`v` starts with `0`. If we do `v = v+1` 20 times, you get `v = 20`.

Therefore, the answer is `20`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Now how would it be changed if an if statement "if ( j > i ) {" was added after the 2nd for loop?